# perlfect DB_File version 1.82

Tags: perl, iis-7

I am trying to get DB_File to work under Perlfect search 3.37 in IIS 7. I've followed the interactions here as best as I could:

http://www.perlfect.com/freescripts/search/readme.shtml

But I'm getting tripped up with the DB_File. In the PPM gui, it says I have version 1.82 but on the Perlfect page it says to use version 1.72. I've tried unintalling 1.82 via command line but it doesn't work (says it can't find it) and via the gui but the option to remove is greyed out.

Does anyone know how to get Perlfect installed? I found this helpful link, but it doesn't help me with my problem:

https://serverfault.com/questions/176321/how-do-i-install-perl-5-8-and-perlfect-on-iis-7-5

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions you linked to, I successfully installed and ran the software. It works fine with DB_File 1.824.

Read version numbers in Perl context as **minimum** required versions.

Comment: Okay, I won't try to get 1.72 installed then. But when I go through the install and get to the place where I run: perl setup.pl it gives me an error: The required DB_File module was not found on your system. But ppm shows it as installed.

Comment: Please [open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with that problem description and also mention your version of ActiveState Perl.